# sql select statement on dataset

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, linq, xml-parsing

i have a `DataSet` which contains different `DataTable` which store data from users.  i writing this `DataSet` to `xml` in the user's computer itself.

```
//after filling both DataTable

 dt1.TableName = "tbl1";
 dt2.TableName = "tbl2";    
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 ds.Tables.Add(dt1);
 ds.Tables.Add(dt2);    
 ds.WriteXml("MyData.XML", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

now, i have a sql select statement(which will be dynamic) which contains a join statement and like also.
is there any way filter these data.

```
DataSet dstbl = new DataSet();
dstbl.ReadXml("MyDataL.XML");
```

if i implement **LINQ**, then how i will create dynamic **LINQ** statement according to select statement, or an way to convert `SQL` select statement(dynamic) into `xml query` so that i can filter on `xml` file
any kind of help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: You could try converting your sql query to xpath.

Comment: how can i achieve this ?

Comment: With a little effort. Look up xpath, it's a query language for xml

Comment: it looked into it, but didnt find any way to convert it